# How to annotate an extended component class in Angular? (Inheritance)

Tags: angular, typescript, inheritance, annotations, angular-components

I have many child components `Child1Component`, etc., how do I write the annotations for the extended parent class `ParentComponent`?

```
/** Parent Component */
/** <----- How to annotate here? */
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(i: INJECTED1, otherParam: string) {
    ...
  }
  ...
}

/** Child Component */
@Component({selector: ..., template: ..., styleUrls: ...})
export class Child1Component extends ParentComponent {
  constructor(i: INJECTED1, j: INJECTED2) {
    super(i, 'otherParam');
  }
  ...
}
```

What I've tried so far (with limited success):

- Annotating `ParentComponent` with `@Directive()` was the closest I found so far, as the angular compiler seems to process that in the desired way. However, this feels wrong, as this clearly is no angular directive. The linter is also not happy with this, expecting a `*.directive.ts` ending on the filename without further tweaking.
- Not annotating `ParentComponent` at all. This results in the Angular Compiler throwing an error `NG2007: Class is using Angular features but is not decorated`.
- Annotating `ParentComponent` with `@Component({template: ''})` feels much better and leaves the linter happy with the file name. But the angular compile now insists on all parameters of `ParentComponent` to be injectables, which they aren't, because they get called by their super class.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, annotating with @Directive is the way to go (at least since angular 9 if I remember correctly, earlier versions of angular didn't need that).

You can rename the ParentComponent to ParentDirective and rename the file accordingly to make the linter happy, or you can configure the linter to ignore this case.

Edit:
I prefer renaming ParentComponent to ParentDirective, because when you think about it a component is basically a directive (i.e. a selector that makes Angular treat certain html tags or html directive) but components have a template and styles while directives don't. Since you parent class doesn't have a template, it makes sense to name it directive.

Comment: Thanks for the edit! Thinking this way about it makes `@Directive` not feel that bad anymore :-)